# PHPexcel, and how to download uncorrupted file?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've searched for hours, and perused dozens of pages trying to find an answer.

I'm using PHPexcel to generate a spreadsheet which I'm saving on my server as a excel 2007 .xlsx file. If I download the .xlsx file directly from the server and open it on my computer, it opens fine. No problem.

If I use a php script to download the file (via `readfile()`), ms excel gives me a "this file is corrupt..." message.

Okay, I've done a hex file compare on the two files, but there's no apparent difference!

This happens on my ubuntu server (running php 5.3.2), as well as wampserver (windows 8, 64 bit environment running PHP 5.3.13).

I've checked everything to make sure there's no \t or \n or any other output sent out before readfile();

I've used ob_start, and ob_end_clean() to make sure no output is being sent.

I'm not using PHP v 5.2.8 with the faulty php_zip.dll binaries.

And get **this!**, this is crazy.

I've even created an excel file using the MS excel program. Nothing wrong with the file. I Upload it directly to my server, and then access it directly via a link. It downloads, and when I try to open it I get a "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened" message.

Here is the direct link if you'd like to try it: http://db.doanddare.org/Lyv6r_y7echVnAcUG4fGUw/testing.xlsx

Yes, is is a direct link to a test file I just created in excel and uploaded. No php processing or headers involved here.

Stack Overflow is my last resort! Thanks for any help.

Oh, and I'm using excel 2013 preview, if that is helpful at all...

Comment: Most common causes of this: Leading/trailing whitespace outside the `<?php ?>` tags (there shouldn't be any) - check all files that are involved in the download, including any that are `include`/`require`d. Check for any PHP errors/warnings generated by the script that may be outputting an error message in the file. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to the very top of the very first script that is executed when downloading the file.

Comment: @DaveRandom I don't think you read all my question. I've tried this with an excel file that was NOT created by php. Still the same problem.

Comment: Oh, and make sure that your script(s) do not have byte order markers in them (save as UTF-8 **without** BOM)

Comment: All the above applies regardless of where the file was created, it's all about how PHP is outputting the file, not how it is creating it. You said yourself `If I download the .xlsx file directly from the server and open it on my computer, it opens fine` - which means that the file itself is fine, and the way you are generating it is fine, the problem is in the way it is being transferred.

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes, but you're still not getting it.., or maybe I"m not :), but the link I posted in my question is a DIRECT link to the file, it is not being read by php

Comment: Do you have a download link to the corrupted file as well?

Comment: Standard answer to this question: open the file in a text editor and see if there is any leading or trailing whitespace in the file, including BOM markers; or any PHP error messages in the content of the file itself

Comment: @DaveRandom If I download the file directly via SFTP or FTP it is fine. But if I download the file via HTTP it is corrupt. Yes, I've looked into BOM. I can't see a problem there.

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, I've done that. Like I said in the question, I've search all the pages on google I can find, and tried all these things already...

Comment: @Emmanuel When I download the file linked above I have no problems opening it (Excel 2007), does the above link work for you? If yes, can you provide the link that *doesn't* work for you?

Comment: If you've done that, then you should be able to see what has corrupted the download - compare that with a file that you've downloaded via ftp if you can't see the difference

Comment: @DaveRandom The link in the question does not work for me...

Comment: @MarkBaker This is what confuses me, I've checked the downloaded file against the original, and can find no difference!

Comment: Interesting - Excel 2007 and Excel 2003 w/format converter don't complain about it for me, I don't have a copy of 2010 to test on handy but I wonder if this is a bug in your version of Excel?

Comment: If there's no difference between the files, then check your headers: are you trying to download an xls file with xlsx headers?

Comment: Note that PHPExcel hasn't been tested with excel 2015 preview.... I didn't even know there was an excel 2015 preview

Comment: @MarkBaker Well, the file in the question is a direct link, no php headers being set at all. But in my php app I"m using the proper xlsx `vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Are you using IE and https? That requires slightly different headers

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, it's the 2013 preview. My bad. http://www.microsoft.com/office/preview/en

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm using Google chrome

Comment: @DaveRandom Here is a link to the same test file being force downloaded by my php app: https://db.doanddare.org/Download-XLSX_PP0cZoSKgsnFWnHihwl-Qw

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21634/discussion-between-emmanuel-and-mark-baker)

Comment: @MarkBaker Still, if I open the file directly with excel, it works fine. Only gets corrupted when I download it via http.

Comment: As a workround - you could output to a temp file on the server rather than php://output, then use a readfile() to actually download - but if there is no difference in the actual file, I'm really struggling to explain it

Comment: I would really like that link to work, I would like to see the file not working for myself and do a binary compare myself. It's not that I don't trust your word. It's that I don't trust anyone. Not even me.

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, it is strange. Perhaps its just my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are having this problem still, it is after all two years since you asked it, but I just had the problem, and found a solution:

You need to change settings in your Excel - it solved the problem for me.

1. Open Excel.
2. Click on "File", then "Options".
3. Select "Trust Center", then select "Trust center settings".
4. Select "Protected view".
5. Uncheck the options under "Protected View" and click "OK".
6. Restart Excel and try to open Excel document.

(Original source: Microsoft Excel help page)